# Opengl Gallery implementation?

Tags: android, opengl-es, widget, gallery

Anyone know of an example of an opengl implementation of something like the Gallery widget? Basically, I am looking for an example of how to horizontally scroll a list of images using opengl. I have seen this behavior in the Gallery 3D app from cooliris but there is ALOT of code in that app and I haven't been able to figure out how it works exactly. I am new to using opengl.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is [texture mapping](http://gpwiki.org/index.php/OpenGL:Tutorials:Tutorial_Framework:Texture_Mapping). [NeHe](http://nehe.gamedev.net/) has the most complete collection of tutorials on OpenGL. I highly recommend you to [take a look](http://nehe.gamedev.net/data/lessons/lesson.asp?lesson=06).

I don't think you're gonna be able to copy/paste code in this case without some understanding of how OpenGL works.

For specific example on how to load 2D textures you can check [this one](http://www.nullterminator.net/gltexture.html).

Comment: I have applications on the market and am capable of writing code... so I am not looking for a copy and paste solution. I just need some example to point me in the right direction.

Comment: OpenGL act as a State Machine. If allow youself to spare a few minutes to read about it, it will make your life much easier when the first problems of copy/pasting code start showing up.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Load thumbnails into a [texture atlas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texture_atlas).  Look into [bin packing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem) for atlas layout ideas.

Step 2: Render a bunch of rectangles with texture coordinates that map into the correct parts of your texture atlas.